# blank screen when return to video from background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-lifecycle

I am using google IMA example to run video in my application, after few changes to make sure it fuffiled my need, I still have an issue which I was not able to reslove, I want the video to be played when app is returned from background or to be paused  depending on the state before the activity stopped.

I have the state, I have the position and still one problem, when the user stops the activity in pause mode. When I return to the video from background, the screen is black until I press start in the controller and there is no need to seek to position it.

I need the preview  image to be shown in pause when return from background.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (mVideoPlayerController != null) {
        mVideoPlayerController.resume();

        if (mVideoPlayerController.isContentStarted())
            if (isPlayedBeforePaused) {
                mVideoPlayer.play();
            } else {

            }
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

and in my video player :

```
 @Override
    public void play() {
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        // Fire callbacks before switching playback state.
        switch (mPlaybackState) {
            case STOPPED:
                for (PlayerCallback callback : mVideoPlayerCallbacks) {
                    callback.onPlay();
                }
                break;
            case PAUSED:
                for (PlayerCallback callback : mVideoPlayerCallbacks) {
                    callback.onResume();
                }
                break;
            default:
                // Already playing; do nothing.
        }
        mPlaybackState = PlaybackState.PLAYING;
    }
```

this is my poor solution that works but i don't want to write that kind of code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (mVideoPlayerController != null) {
        mVideoPlayerController.resume();


        if (mVideoPlayerController.isContentStarted())
            if (isPlayedBeforePaused) {
                mVideoPlayer.play();
            } else {
                mVideoPlayer.play();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mVideoPlayer.pause();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: have same problem with using exoplayer :)

Comment: Are you calling `MediaPlayer#setDisplay()` after the app resumes?

Comment: i cant set display on resume , it will trow illegal state exception . and the media player have set display already before

Comment: @Amir, Did you find any solution to the same with Exoplayer

Answer (score 0):

handle pausing playback in `onPause`, also save the `playbackPosition`.
In `onResume` check the previous `playbackPosition` with the current. If they mismatch, reinit your `MediaPlayer` seek to `playbackPosition` and resume playback with `play()`, otherwise just execute `play()`.

Views may also need to be reinitialised. This could be the reason for the black screen.

Comment: i have done this but this is not the problem , even after i return from background the seek marker is in the correct position , and you can move it any where on the scroll but you will still see black screen until play is pressed

Comment: what does `play()` do? Not `MediaPlayer.play()` but your `play()`. Does it reinit views?

Answer (score 0):

my only solution is to play and pause the video but only after it prepared .

so on my main activity

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (mVideoPlayerController != null) {
        mVideoPlayerController.resume();


        if (mVideoPlayerController.isContentStarted())
            if (isPlayedBeforePaused) {
                mVideoPlayer.play();
            } else {
                // set pause request will notify on prepare to play and pause
                // this fix the bug that on pause when return from background it shows black screen
                mVideoPlayerController.mVideoTracker.setPauseRequest();
            }

    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

and on my video tracker (Video view)

```
super.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mMediaPlayer = mp;
        if (mPauseRequest) {
            play();
            pause();
            mPauseRequest = false;
        }
    }
});
```

i know it is not the best way to go but it the best i found that is bug free and such thing is exist (-:

hope it will help someone