# Vlc player black screen on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, vlc, libvlcsharp

the video is playing normally, but if you open another application and go back, vlc will show a black screen with a only sound. (Android 8.0.0, last version of nuget package)

```js
LibVLC libVLC = new LibVLC("--preferred-resolution=-1", " --log-verbose=3", "--no-gnutls-system-trust");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Media media = new Media(libVLC, playerUrl, FromType.FromLocation);
VideoView1.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: When you go back to your app, does that same code execute again? If so, you've started a second mediaplayer, but did not tell the first one to stop. The first one (which you are no longer seeing) still has the video. I'm not familiar with mediaplayer, but the basic concept is that in your Xamarin.Android project's app's (or maybe mainactivity's) OnPause you need to "clean up" active resources (stop the video, maybe Dispose also), then save info (maybe in a Bundle) to tell your app what "state" it was in. if you want to get back to the same location in video in OnCreate or OnResume.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, No, the media player is created once when you click on the element. Yes, creating a new media player might help, but it's a very bad idea.. thank you for your response

Comment: I was not suggesting that you create a new media player. Rather, I was *asking* if you breakpoint your code, *does that code get executed again* when it returns to the app. (If it did, then that would create a new player, so you'd need to do something like what I suggested.) Good if it does not. Anyway, the symptom suggests that leaving the app and returning to it results in media player being in a bad state. The fix must involve "doing something" when your app goes into background, then "doing something else" when it resumes.

Comment: Probably because the "surface" changes when app resumes. Maybe investigate discussions at the android level, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/6347924/199364.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I'll have to create a new mediaplayer, and a new videoview. Unfortunately...

Comment: One person claims to have it working for the android mediaplayer. Don't know if this applies to vlc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34854913/199364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, background support needs a bit of ceremony due to how the OS works. Simply, it means you need to recreate a `VideoView` and set your existing `MediaPlayer` on it to have video working when coming back from the background.

Sample demonstrating this is available https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/-/tree/master/ForegroundBackground